# Android compose: Surface can have only one direct measurable child

Tags: android, image, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I'm new to Jetpack compose, I have create a composable like this:

```
  Column(
        Modifier.clickable(onClick = onclick)
            .fillMaxWidth().background(pastelGray)
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        Card(backgroundColor = Color.Cyan) {
   //         Image(asset = vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_coupon_back), modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth())
            Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)) {
                Text(text = coupon.couponTitle, color = Color.Red, fontSize = 20.sp)
                Text(text = coupon.couponSubTitle, color = Color.Black, fontSize = 13.sp)
                Text(text = coupon.couponDateTitle, color = Color.Gray, fontSize = 11.sp)
            }
        }
    }
```

When I add that commented image I got this error:

```
Surface can have only one direct measurable child!
```

I could not find the reason so far.

Answer (score 5):

Because `Card()` composable used in your code uses Surface under the hood:

```
@Composable
fun Card(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    shape: Shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium,
    backgroundColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.surface,
    contentColor: Color = contentColorFor(backgroundColor),
    border: BorderStroke? = null,
    elevation: Dp = 1.dp,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    Surface(
        modifier = modifier,
        shape = shape,
        color = backgroundColor,
        contentColor = contentColor,
        elevation = elevation,
        border = border,
        content = content
    )
}
```

source: [Official Card Implementation code](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:compose/material/material/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/Card.kt?q=Card&ss=androidx%2Fplatform%2Fframeworks%2Fsupport)

And Surface is a kind like `ScrollView` doesn't accept more than one direct child. So you need to wrap your code inside `Card()` into a single parent that is a direct child of `Card` or in other words direct child of `Surface`, example:

```
Card(backgroundColor = Color.Cyan) {
     CardContent()
}

private fun CardContent() {
        Column() {
            // Image(asset = vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_coupon_back), modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth())
               Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)) {
                      Text(text = coupon.couponTitle, color = Color.Red, fontSize = 20.sp)
                      Text(text = coupon.couponSubTitle, color = Color.Black, fontSize = 13.sp)
                      Text(text = coupon.couponDateTitle, color = Color.Gray, fontSize = 11.sp)
               }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FrameLayout is like a Stack/Box, It will never give any error if you add more elements to it and with the most recently added child on top

Comment: Oh, Thanks for correcting me I know that you can add as many children as you want in FrameLayout, but they will also overlap each other. That being said when I've mentioned FrameLayout in my answer I just wanted to say you cannot add two elements in this layout at the same level. This was my point of view.

Comment: @MR3YY I think Surface matches the Android ScrollView behaviour. Right?

Comment: @AndrewChelix exactly!! I will edit my answer to mention `ScrollView` instead, thanks